# Where is the loot_tables folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can someone please tell me where I can find the `loot_tables` folder in my Minecraft directory? There is no such folder in `assets` or `saves\worldname\data`. This is in 1.10.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assets are in the respective JAR file in `.minecraft/versions/<version>/<version>.jar`.
(On Windows 10, hold the windows button and press 'r'. type in '%appdata%', then navigate to '.minecraft', but this depends whether you are using the default launcher or something else like Curse).
Opening that with an archive manager (7-zip, WinRAR etc) will give you the internal folder structure.

Navigate to `assets/minecraft/loot_tables`. There they are.

Comment: How do I find the Minecraft JAR file for windows 10?  ..Sorry.

Comment: @ReaLord I added this information to my answer